# Java - Check 2D Array for 3-6 of the same value

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D Array **map[6][6]** and the values are randomly generated in a for loop

This is what the output looks like (In integer values)

[image]

There are 5 different brick colors

I want to be able to check for 3-6 of the same brick color in a row (Horizontally and Vertically) when they are randomly generated, and when the user changes a brick value

I am also fairly new to Java (3 Months or so) so I would like a simple way to do this (I do not know things like objects)

Comment: That's cute John...If you want to do anything in Java that has some sort of meaningful use then you will need to learn about Objects. After all, Java is a Object-Oriented programming language. In any case, what do yo mean by 3-6?

Comment: For example, in the image I posted there are three 3's in a row in the fourth row starting on column 4. I want to be able to check for these horizontally and vertically.

Comment: So what you are saying then that row 4 should be detected (because it has three 3's horizontally) and rows 4, 5, and 6 should be detected (because there are 3's in each row of the 6th column) creating three 3's vertically ??

Comment: map[3][3] map[4][3] and map[5][3] should be detected as 3 in a row with a value of 3

Comment: Am I looking at this wrong? [3][3] = 3, [4][3] = 1, [5][3] = 5. What I see is: {[3][3] = 3, [3][4] = 3, [3][5] = 3},  {[3][5] = 3,  [4][5] = 3, [5][5] = 3}. Both sets indicate three 3's

Comment: @DevilsHnd For what he's trying to achieve, he does not need to have deep knowledge of OOP since this is procedural programmation.

Comment: @DevilsHnd That was just an example, but yes both of those sets would be detected

Comment: Can we see your code for the random number generation since this should be handled there (via a method) so that these occurrences don't make it into the Array. Or do you actually want them in the Array?

Comment: My code is here http://pastebin.com/yNCAM2Bx, it just assigns values to the positions in the array which will later be converted into bricks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay John. Holiday stuff to do and guests. It's that time of year. :)

In any case. I quickly developed two run-able classes you can use to play with a method you have actually named. It's called the **hasThreeInSix()** even though it's not limited to any three or six that's the name we're going to give it.

Even though it's specifically designed for 2D integer Arrays it wouldn't take much effort to modify it for whatever.

The first run-able below is for testing only. It simply shows you what is going on via the output console (pane)

The second run-able is is what you may want to apply to carry out your task. Take a close look at your **randomBoard()** method so that you can see how we've used the **hasThreeInSix()** method.

Here is the code for the run-able Test Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TESTThreeAndSixMethod {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";

        while (!input.equals("quit")) {
            Echo("\nPress ENTER to generate random number blocks\n"
                    + "for 2 dimensional array or enter 'quit' to exit:");
            input = userInput.nextLine();
            if (input.toLowerCase().equals("quit")) { System.exit(0); }

            int[][] x = new int[6][6];
            randomBoard(x);
        }

        userInput.close();
    }


    public static void randomBoard (int[][] x) {
        int[][] map = new int[6][6];
        Echo("");
        for (int i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++) {
            String arrayString = "";
            for (int j = 0 ; j < x[i].length ; j++) {
                int tmp = 1 + (int) (Math.random () * 5);
                map[i][j] = tmp;
                arrayString+= String.valueOf(map[i][j]);
            }

            // Play with the maxHorizontal, maxVertical, and numberToCheckFor
            // parameters. What you see here now will never allow any array 
            // row of elements contain 3 of any same consecutive single digit
            // values either horizontally of vertically. Nowhere should there
            // ever be any three of the same digits either vertically or hor-
            // zontally. If you just want to deal with a specific number from
            // 0 to 9 then change the -1 to that number.
            String result = hasThreeInSix(map, i, 3, 3, -1);
            if (!"".equals(result)) { 
                Echo(arrayString + "  --  " + result); 
                //i--;
            } 
            else { Echo(arrayString); }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Detect specified same single digit elements either or horizontally and or vertically within
     * a 2D Array. This method is to be used during the creation of the 2D Array so as to eliminate 
     * specified same elements from being placed into the Array.<br><br>
     * 
     * @param array (Integer 2D Array) the array being created.<br>
     * 
     * @param currentIndexRow (Integer) The most currently added ROW index number.<br>
     * 
     * @param maxHorizontal (Integer) The number of same digit elements to detect horizontally. If
     * 0 is supplied then no horizontal check is done. 1 can not be supplied. If it is then the method 
     * simply returns null string which ultimately indicates that the array row is good. 1 is not 
     * permitted because this will just lead to a infinite loop.<br>
     * 
     * @param maxVertical (Integer) The same number of digit elements to detect vertically. If 0 is
     * supplied then no Vertical check is done. 1 can not be supplied. If it is then the method simply
     * returns null string which ultimately indicates that the array row is good. 1 is not permitted
     * because this will just lead to a infinite loop.<br>
     * 
     * @param numberToCheckFor (Integer) The number to check for to see if there is a repetitive
     * sequence horizontally or vertically within the Array. Any single digit number from 0 to 9
     * can be suppled. If -1 is supplied then this method will check for repetitive sequences for
     * ALL numbers from 0 to 9 both horizontally and vertically.<br>
     * 
     * @return (String) If a null string ("") is returned then this indicates that the Array Row is
     * good. If a vertical and or horizontal sequence is detected then a string is returned indicating
     * either the row sequence value for horizontal detection or the rows and columns detected for 
     * vertical detection.
     */
    public static String hasThreeInSix(int[][] array, int currentIndexRow, int maxHorizontal, 
                                       int maxVertical, int numberToCheckFor) {
        String indexString = "";
        int n = 1, check = numberToCheckFor; 

        if (maxHorizontal > 0) {
            // Check for horizontal values...
            String aStrg = "";
            if (maxHorizontal < 2 || maxVertical < 2) { 
                Echo("\n\u001B[31mmaxHorizontal and or maxVertical Parameter Error!\n"
                        + "\u001B[34mNeither of these parameters can be less than 2\n"
                        + "otherwise an infinite loop will occure! Exiting Method!\u001B[39;49m"); 
                return "";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array[currentIndexRow].length; i++) {
                aStrg+= array[currentIndexRow][i];
            }

            if (numberToCheckFor == -1) { n = 10; }
            for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                String valToCheckFor = "";
                if (numberToCheckFor == -1) { check = c; }
                for (int i = 1; i <= maxHorizontal; i++) {
                    valToCheckFor+= String.valueOf(check);
                }  
                if (aStrg.contains(valToCheckFor)) { return "Horizontal " + maxHorizontal + " Detected! (" + aStrg + ")"; }
            }
        }

        if (maxVertical > 0) {
            // Check for vertical values...
            ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
                String aString = "";
                for (int j = 0 ; j < array[i].length ; j++) {
                    aString+= String.valueOf(array[i][j]);
                }
                if (!"000000".equals(aString)) { listString.add(aString); }
            }

            n = 1; check = numberToCheckFor; 
            if (numberToCheckFor == -1) { n = 10; }
            for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                if (numberToCheckFor == -1) { check = c; }

                String itemToLocate = String.valueOf(check);
                String foundInfo = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < listString.get(0).length(); i++) {
                    int counter = 0; 
                    for (int j = 0; j < listString.size(); j++) {
                        if (listString.get(j).substring(i,i+1).equals(itemToLocate)) {
                            if ("".equals(foundInfo)) { foundInfo = "Vertical " + maxVertical + " Detection in Column " + (i+1) + " On Rows: -> " + (j+1); }
                            else { foundInfo+= ", " + (j+1); } 
                            counter++; 
                        }
                        else {counter = 0; foundInfo = ""; }
                        if (counter == maxVertical) { 
                            indexString = foundInfo; 
                            break; 
                        }
                    }
                    if (!"".equals(indexString)) { break; }
                }
                if (!"".equals(indexString)) { break; }
            }
        }
        return indexString;
    }

    private static void Echo(Object object) {
        System.out.println(object); 
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the runable class which contains the workable **hasThreeInSix()** method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreeAndSixMethod {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";

        while (!input.equals("quit")) {
            Echo("\nPress ENTER to generate random number blocks\n"
                    + "for 2 dimensional array or enter 'quit' to exit:");
            input = userInput.nextLine();
            if (input.toLowerCase().equals("quit")) { System.exit(0); }

            int[][] x = new int[6][6];
            randomBoard(x);
        }

        userInput.close(); 
    }

    public static void randomBoard (int[][] x) {
        int[][] map = new int[6][6];
        Echo("");
        for (int i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++) {
            String arrayString = "";
            for (int j = 0 ; j < x[i].length ; j++) {
                int tmp = 1 + (int) (Math.random () * 5);
                map[i][j] = tmp;
                // you can remove the line below if you don't want to 
                // display anything in output.
                arrayString+= String.valueOf(map[i][j]);
            }

            // Play with the maxHorizontal, maxVertical, and numberToCheckFor
            // parameters. What you see here now will never allow any array 
            // row of elements contain 3 of any same consecutive single digit
            // values either horizontally of vertically. Nowhere should there
            // ever be any three of the same digits either vertically or hor-
            // zontally. If you just want to deal with a specific number from
            // 0 to 9 then change the -1 to that number.
            String result = hasThreeInSix(map, i, 3, 3, -1);
            if (!"".equals(result)) { i--; } 

            // You can remove the else{} line below if you 
            // don't want to display anything in output.
            else { Echo(arrayString); }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Detect specified same single digit elements either or horizontally and or vertically within
     * a 2D Array. This method is to be used during the creation of the 2D Array so as to eliminate 
     * specified same elements from being placed into the Array.<br><br>
     * 
     * @param array (Integer 2D Array) the array being created.<br>
     * 
     * @param currentIndexRow (Integer) The most currently added ROW index number.<br>
     * 
     * @param maxHorizontal (Integer) The number of same digit elements to detect horizontally. If
     * 0 is supplied then no horizontal check is done. 1 can not be supplied. If it is then the method 
     * simply returns null string which ultimately indicates that the array row is good. 1 is not 
     * permitted because this will just lead to a infinite loop.<br>
     * 
     * @param maxVertical (Integer) The same number of digit elements to detect vertically. If 0 is
     * supplied then no Vertical check is done. 1 can not be supplied. If it is then the method simply
     * returns null string which ultimately indicates that the array row is good. 1 is not permitted
     * because this will just lead to a infinite loop.<br>
     * 
     * @param numberToCheckFor (Integer) The number to check for to see if there is a repetitive
     * sequence horizontally or vertically within the Array. Any single digit number from 0 to 9
     * can be suppled. If -1 is supplied then this method will check for repetitive sequences for
     * ALL numbers from 0 to 9 both horizontally and vertically.<br>
     * 
     * @return (String) If a null string ("") is returned then this indicates that the Array Row is
     * good. If a vertical and or horizontal sequence is detected then a string is returned indicating
     * either the row sequence value for horizontal detection or the rows and columns detected for 
     * vertical detection.
     */
    public static String hasThreeInSix(int[][] array, int currentIndexRow, int maxHorizontal, 
                                       int maxVertical, int numberToCheckFor) {
        String indexString = "";
        int n = 1, check = numberToCheckFor; 

        if (maxHorizontal > 0) {
            // Check for horizontal values...
            String aStrg = "";
            if (maxHorizontal < 2 || maxVertical < 2) { 
                Echo("\n\u001B[31mmaxHorizontal and or maxVertical Parameter Error!\n"
                        + "\u001B[34mNeither of these parameters can be less than 2\n"
                        + "otherwise an infinite loop will occure! Exiting Method!\u001B[39;49m"); 
                return "";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array[currentIndexRow].length; i++) {
                aStrg+= array[currentIndexRow][i];
            }

            if (numberToCheckFor == -1) { n = 10; }
            for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                String valToCheckFor = "";
                if (numberToCheckFor == -1) { check = c; }
                for (int i = 1; i <= maxHorizontal; i++) {
                    valToCheckFor+= String.valueOf(check);
                }  
                if (aStrg.contains(valToCheckFor)) { return "Horizontal " + maxHorizontal + " Detected! (" + aStrg + ")"; }
            }
        }

        if (maxVertical > 0) {
            // Check for vertical values...
            ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
                String aString = "";
                for (int j = 0 ; j < array[i].length ; j++) {
                    aString+= String.valueOf(array[i][j]);
                }
                if (!"000000".equals(aString)) { listString.add(aString); }
            }

            n = 1; check = numberToCheckFor; 
            if (numberToCheckFor == -1) { n = 10; }
            for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                if (numberToCheckFor == -1) { check = c; }

                String itemToLocate = String.valueOf(check);
                String foundInfo = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < listString.get(0).length(); i++) {
                    int counter = 0; 
                    for (int j = 0; j < listString.size(); j++) {
                        if (listString.get(j).substring(i,i+1).equals(itemToLocate)) {
                            if ("".equals(foundInfo)) { foundInfo = "Vertical " + maxVertical + " Detection in Column " + (i+1) + " On Rows: -> " + (j+1); }
                            else { foundInfo+= ", " + (j+1); } 
                            counter++; 
                        }
                        else {counter = 0; foundInfo = ""; }
                        if (counter == maxVertical) { 
                            indexString = foundInfo; 
                            break; 
                        }
                    }
                    if (!"".equals(indexString)) { break; }
                }
                if (!"".equals(indexString)) { break; }
            }
        }
        return indexString;
    }

    private static void Echo(Object object) {
        System.out.println(object); 
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.